# How get Date from Database in Other country language?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I need help to get date value from database in Dhivehi language format.

```
$sql("SELECT `id`,`name`, DATE_FORMAT(`date`, '%Y %M') FROM tablname");
```

I need the date output to be formatted like "ސެޕްޓެމްބަރ2015"

Comment: What is the problem exactly? Do you get wrong characters?

Comment: What you mean by _Other Country language_

Comment: In Hindi, Arabic , Maldives language like that. 
For example: '25.MAY.2015' that in this language.

Answer (score 0):

If it's about the output, I'd recommend that you do the "styling" in PHP, using for example [strftime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php) in combination with [setlocale](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php). You can call `strftime` with a timestamp, so your MySQL query should deliver that. Depending on what field type your `date` field in the database is, you might need MySQL functions like [UNIX_TIMESTAMP](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp).

Just in case you come across it, the MySQL field type `TIMESTAMP` is something different ;)